# issue in fetching html components from ES6 script

Tags: javascript, html, dom, es6-promise

Till now I was using require to import the npm installed moudles but, when I use import, my modules are being imported but I am not able to fetch the component of my html file.

here is my html code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="value"></p>
    <h1 style="margin: auto">Working</h1>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is my js file(index.js)

```
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";

var pval = document.getElementById("value");
.....
```

when I run **node index.js** it shows,

```
var pval = document.getElementById("value");
           ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at file:///D:/alchemy%20practical/javascript%20fundamental/node/index.js:3:12
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)
```

any idea why I'm getting this error?

I mentioned the type as module in my package.json and searched a lot on internet but no one was mentioning this problem.

Comment: node does not have "document" unless you import a DOM handler

Comment: you can use jsdom module for that.